# Easiest way to add file upload progress bar (paperclip) Apache/Paperclip/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

is there an easy upload progress bar example for rails upload based on paperclip and apache server? The examples I've seen so far are either outdated or really confusing to me.

Appreciate your help!

Pier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) combined with the [Rack Raw Upload](https://github.com/newbamboo/rack-raw-upload) gem.

Has been working perfectly for me in Rails 3.2 applications.

Comment: Why is the Rack Raw Upload gem useful in this case?  Newer versions of Fine Uploader already (by default) sends all upload POST requests multipart encoded.  Is there something else provided by this gem?

Comment: Ajax uploads are raw uploads, this gem makes them available (through a rack middleware) to your rails application in the standard params hash. Read this for more information: http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/07/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads

Comment: By default, all upload requests sent by Fine Uploader (since version 3.3) are done using FormData for File API supported browsers.  Even previous to 3.3, this was possible by setting a couple options.  So, it seems like this gem is not necessary unless you are using a very old version of Fine Uploader.

Comment: According to the article you linked to, as well as the documentation for the gem, "raw uploads" via ajax are those that are not MPE (do not use FormData), and, ostensibly, do not have parameters included in the request payload as form fields.  All Fine Uploader upload requests are MPE by default and include all params in the payload.  Server-side, the requests are indistinguishable from a POST upload request sent via an actual form submit.  The readme for the gem even seems to state that it will not transform requests with a Content-Type of "multipart/form-data".